# How do I write a counterpart program that can be called remotely to perform computations on a remote machine

Tags: c#, mono, network-programming, remote-access

I have written a program that generates checksums on files. Everything works fine on a local machine but slows down immensely and turns to **** when I branch out to remote machines due to network speed (obviously).

How do I go about writing a counterpart program that can be called upon remotely to calculate the checksums on the remote machine and respond with the hash?

Ideally I would love full remote deployment but I have access to the remote machine for install and setup.

Targets are Windows and Ubuntu/FreeBSD using Mono.

**Edit**

I didn't explain myself as well as I had thought. I have a server which hosts a large number of large files and rather than stream those files over the network to my personal computer to calculate the checksum (as I have been) I'm looking for a way to run a daemon on the server that I can ask to calculate the checksum for a file it hosts locally and give me the hash.

Comment: Have you concidered using TcpClient and TcpListener to send the data or make the remote calls?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet but I will look at TcpClient/Listener.

What I'm most confused about is how to start the remote program and pass information to it. Does it have to be running as a service / in the background?

Comment: It does not have to be in the background, but it's a good idea. I use backgroundWorkers to establish the connection between the "client" and the "server". I can leave an answer explaining how to do this, does that sound good? If yes, is the process something like this: "Send checksum -> Counterpart calculates -> Recieve checksum"?

Comment: Yes please! The process is something like: Ask counterpart to calculate checksum for file X -> Counterpart calculates checksum -> Receive checksum

Comment: Now that i think about it. Why dont you just calculate the checksum in a process in the background in the main program? A backgroundWorker won't halt the application and you can make the backgroundWorker automatically run some code, when it has finished it's process and through that "process-done-code" return the checksum. It will be easyer this way, because otherwise you'll have to send the file to another computer before using the counterpart program to calculate the checksum and then send the checksum back to the main program

Comment: You've sort of hit on the idea of using a counterpart. The idea is to be able to hash large files on a remote computer without processing them over a network. I want to be able to tell the remote computer which file I want hashed, have it hash it locally, and then send me the hash.

Comment: Did I scare you off? I haven't heard from you in a while, that's all :D

Comment: Not at all, I've just had to put this on the backburner and haven't had a chance to get stuck into it. I'll be making headway this weekend (hopefully) and will hammer you with questions then :)

Comment: So my current answer works well for you?

Comment: Did you get it to work? Getting a bit lonely here :D

Answer (score 0):

And now a complete reformation of the answer. While still commenting as well as I could, I've tried to keep it as "basic" / "general" as I could without creating loose ends.

---

**Main Program (Normal Method)**

```
public async Task<byte[]> ConnectToCounterpart(string dataToSend)
{
    // === Sending empty strings breaks the program ===
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataToSend))
        return null;


    // === Variables n' Stuff ===
    string counterPartIP = "127.0.0.1"; // The ip of the computer running counterpart program. (127.0.0.1 is the localhost/current computer).
    int counterPartPort = 50_000; // The port which the counterpart program listens to


    // === Getting a connection ===
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient(counterPartIP, counterPartPort); // Connect to the counterpart program

    NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream(); // Get the networkStream between the main and counterpart program
    nwStream.ReadTimeout = 5_000; // Give the counterpart program 5 seconds to do its thing


    // === Convert the "dataToSend" to a byte-array ===
    byte[] bytesToSend = Encoding.UTF7.GetBytes(dataToSend); // An array with the bytes of the string (UTF7 lets you keep "cpecial characters like Æ, Ø, Å, Á etc.")


    // === Send the file-bytes ===
    await nwStream.WriteAsync(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length); // Send the file-bytes to the counterpart program


    // ==========================================
    // At this point counterpart is doing work
    // ==========================================


    byte[] returnBytes = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize]; // The byte-array this method returns
    try
    {
        // === Recieve the reply ===
        int numberOfBytesRecieved = await nwStream.ReadAsync(returnBytes, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize); // Receve the checksum from the counterpart and tthe ammount of sent bytes


        // === Crop return-array to the recieved bytes ===
        Array.Resize(ref returnBytes, numberOfBytesRecieved);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error while retrieving"); // Show error

        returnBytes = null; // Set returnbytes to null
    }


    // === Close and dispose stream ===
    nwStream.Close();
    nwStream.Dispose();


    // === Return the byte-array ===
    return returnBytes;
}
```

In this piece of code you've probably noticed "`async`", "`Task<byte[]>`" and "`await`". "`Task<byte[]>`" is the same as "`byte[]`" (kinda) and is used because the "async" modifier requires it. (About async programming: https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/hh156513(v=vs.110).aspx)

The returned type will in any case still be "byte[]". "Async" and "Await" will be explained further in a "bit" (Byte, bit... Puns).

**Counterpart Code (BackgroundWorker)**

```
private void BackgroundWorkerCalculate_Counterpart_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // === Variables n' Stuff ===
    int listeningPort = 50_000; // The port which the counterpart program listens to


    // === Start listening ===
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, listeningPort); // Listen to the port
    listener.Start();


    // Infinite loop for infinite computations
    while (true)
    {
        // === Getting a connection ===
        TcpClient connection = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        NetworkStream nwStream = connection.GetStream();


        // === Get the recieved bytes ===
        byte[] recievedBytes = new byte[connection.ReceiveBufferSize]; // Create a buffer for the incomming file-bytes
        int numberOfBytesRecieved = nwStream.Read(recievedBytes, 0, connection.ReceiveBufferSize); // Read the bytes to the buffer


        // === Convert recieved bytes to a string ===
        string recievedString = Encoding.UTF7.GetString(recievedBytes, 0, numberOfBytesRecieved);



        // === Understanding the recieved data ===
        /* Lets say recievedString == "[path]" */

        byte[] replyBytes = new byte[] { 1 }; // Bytes to reply to the main program

        try
        {
            using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create()) // Create the hashing protocol
            {
                using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(recievedString, FileMode.Open)) // Open the file to hash
                {
                    replyBytes = md5.ComputeHash(fileStream); // replyBytes now contains the hash
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        { } // If file doesn't exist, then replyBytes stays as { 1 }, which will be returned if things goes wrong


        // === Send the reply to main program ===
        nwStream.Write(replyBytes, 0, replyBytes.Length);
    }
}
```

This code still does the same: Recieves some data and returns some data. You can now modify the "Understanding the recieved data" part to your needs. For example checking if the received path is a file or a directory, thus differentiating between "GetChecksum" (referring to a file) and "GetSubelements" (referring to a directory).

**Main Program (Usage)**

```
private async void ButtonCalculate_Counterpart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This is how you use the method
    byte[] replyBytes = await ConnectToCounterpart(@"folder\file.txt");

    // "async" makes the given method "asyncronous", so that it runs parallell to other tings 
    // "await" will prevent a time-consumeing method-call from "halting" or "blocking" the main process.


    // Check if things went wrong
    if (replyBytes == new byte { 1 }) // As mentioned ealier in the backgroundWorker code
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong with the hashing. Is the path correct?", "Could not hash")
        return;
    }


    // If you want the reply as a normal string
    string replyString = Encoding.UTF7.GetString(replyBytes, 0, replyBytes.Length);

    // If you want the reply as a checksum
    string checkSum = BitConverter.ToString(replyBytes);
 }
```

The comments here should explain things.

---

Note: You can easily use other encryptions besides UTF7, just be consistent througout the code.

Note 2: If the data sent ever becomes larger than 50 kB, then there is a risk of not all data being sent, because of the way I've programmed this. If that becomes a problem, I can do some changes. Those changes are just more complicated.

Note 3: If you want to access the counterpart from a seperate network (over the internet and not locally), then you'll need to do some port forwarding on the router to which the counterart is connected.

Note 4: Remember that, if you pass a path like this "`Folder\File.txt`" to the counterpart, then the counterpart will look at the directory "`C:\Users\...\...\FolderWithProgramExe\Folder\File.txt`". If you instead pass "`C:\Folder\File.txt`" (note "`C:\`" in the beginning) to the counterpart, then the counterpart will look at exactly the location "`C:\Folder\File.txt`" on the computer.

I hope this will be of use to you now. As said, I've tried to keep the code as "plastic" / "easily modifiable" as possible, so that you can adjust it to your needs.

Comment: Not quite but the TCP code is great to get my head around (never done network programming before). I didn't explain myself as well as I had thought. The idea is I have a server which hosts a large number of large files and rather than stream those files over the network to my computer to calculate the checksum (as I have been) I'm looking for a way to run a daemon on the server that I can ask to calculate the checksum for a file it hosts locally and give me the hash.

C# hashes are returned as byte[], to get a hex string you call BitConverter.ToString(byte[]) or loop it yourself

Comment: @Michael Oooooohhhhh. I see now. Do you want to identify the file by filename, an id for the file or through a list you can stream from the counterpart? Does the counterpart keep track of the hashable files or do you just put a lot of files in a single folder?

Comment: Right now I'm thinking I would pass a path from a known share that the remote would be set up to dereference. But I'm open to it if there's a better way.

Comment: @Michael What if the counterpart had a folder called "Database". This database-folder then has a file called "file.txt". To refer to "file.txt" from the main-program you simply type "file.txt". If "file.txt" then was put in a subfolder, let's say "Database\subfolder", then you'd refer to "file.txt" from the main-program as so: "subfolder\file.txt". Sound good?

Comment: Ah yes, I get what you mean! Is the way I was suggesting even possible or am I looking at a world of hurt trying to do it that way?

Comment: @Michael Not at all, this will be fun. I'll make the modifications and update my answer. Also, should the main program be able to browse through the files on the counterpart? Maybe commands like "checksum [filename]" and "browse [directory]", if you get what I mean? Is this a good idea or too much?

Comment: @Michael After reading your comment again I believe i misunderstood what you wrote. Is the "known share" a list of paths that people recieve and the "path from the known share" a complete path to a file anywhere on the counterpart computer (no fixed database-folder)? Also: Anything is possible.

Comment: The main program needs a way to access the files on the remote to tell which ones need to be hashed (this is solved). If I continue to access the remote with a network share as I have been I will need to convert the path I see to one it can use (easy enough since I know the share I'm mapped into). If the remote can be polled to give a list of files and folders that's another path to the same result. If you can help me with the TCP communication to generate and return a hash I can extend that to include browsing.

Comment: @Michael I've now, as you requested, changed my answer to be a guide through TCP communications and also a guide showing how the counterpart can generate and return a checksum / hash. I've also included a description of how to use the code. Do remember to call `backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()` on the counterpart to start the listener. If you need more explaination, then just ask.